# Is there a bool for inNull(sqlite3_stmt *, int col) to allow me to check for it?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

In my database, there are a lot of options where an entry ISNT required at start, so it is nullable.  I was looking through the C++ api for SQLite3 and i didnt find anything from first glance ( http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html) as to how to handle this.  The only thing i came across was what is returned when you request a column and the column is null (shown here: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html).

The thing is that, might not be throing errors because 0 is a valid solution for a lot of common things (As a programmer we usually start counts at 0).

What i want to do is find a boolean statement if there is one, so that way i can check if null before extracting the data.   That way, a proper flag can be returned instead of 0.

Anyone else have issues here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check the type of the column before getting the data (which will do a conversion). You do it with [`sqlite3_column_type`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html), which returns `SQLITE_NULL` for a NULL value:

```
bool isNull(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, int iCol)
{
    return sqlite3_column_type(stmt, iCol) == SQLITE_NULL;
}
```

Comment: so, you do a _step() and then check that column(stmt, iCol) and it will return NULL if the contents datatype is null?

Comment: @Fallenreaper: you do `step()`. Then `sqlite3_column_type` will return `SQLITE_NULL` if the content is NULL. The function `isNull` that I wrote will return `true` if the content is NULL.

Comment: Yea thats what i was thinking, thanks.  Thats what i was looking for. :)

Comment: I was curious though, can you assign null to the base datatypes of c++ and string?   I was thinking you might.  example:   int a; if(isnull(stmt,col)){ a = null;}else{ a = 5; } ?

Comment: @Fallenreaper: no, you cannot. You may use Boost.Optional though.

Comment: ahh ok.  I know in things like c#, you can do int? a which would allow an int OR NULL.  I wasnt sure if that was something you can do in C++, or if that was just due to c# being higher level, and had some wrappers which handle all of that information.

Comment: @Fallenreaper: it is not that C# is higher level. In C# `int?` is a shorthand for `System.Nullable<int>`. In C++ you do not have the short syntax, but you still can implement the same functionality as `int?` in C#. In fact [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) does this.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Well, i cant use Boost BUT im sure there is a small workaround i can create to allow some sort of Nullable<T>